# How can I add a Raster Calculator tool on QGIS Processing Modeler?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to add the Raster Calculator to a model I'm creating using the Processing Modeler of QGIS 2.6 Brighton. It does not allow me to add the normal Raster Calculator tool under Raster, so I tried using GDAL Raster Calculator tool but it only allows me to include 6 layers into the mathematical expression; I need to include 7 layers.

Is there any other way to add the Raster Calculator to the Model in which I can include all of my 7 layers into my mathematical expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also **SAGA / Grid - Calculus / Raster calculator** which should allow you to use your 7 grids directly in one expression. Please be aware with SAGA Raster Calculator the way to use your files in expression is g1, g2, g3...

If the only problem is that *GDAL raster calculator* allows you to work with only 6 layers then you can also **break your calculation into 2 or more steps** and chain raster calculator process. *GDAL raster calculator* itself can work with 26 letters (A-Z) but I don't see any option how to extend slots in the GUI of modeler.

Let's say you want to do:

SUM = A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H

You need to break it into:

- SUM1 = A+B+C+D
- SUM2 = E+F+G+H
- SUM = SUM1 + SUM2

(Btw if you really want to get *SUM*, there is *Grids sum* under *SAGA /Grid - Calculus* together with some more simplified tools/algorithms)